# jax-rs pass more than one JSON object to java method call

Tags: json, rest, cxf, jax-rs

I am using CXF Jax-rs, wanted to pass 2 JSON objects as arguments to my rest service method.

I was able to pass one object as argument.

Appreciate any help.

thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by passing a "JSON object" (not the best terminology but I think I know what is meant here) you mean you are passing a parameter to a service method via an entity body, and specifying its content type.

As you know in JAX-RS only one parameter can be bare (that is, not marked with `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam` or `@MatrixParam` etc.) and that single unannotated parameter comes from the entity body.

So you cannot pass two such parameters.  It is not allowed.

What you can do is encode your entity body of the request in JSON as follows:

```
{ "param1": { .... }, "param2": { .... } }
```

which fakes two "objects" into one.

Comment: that is exactly I was struggling with. thank you so much for the response